# What is the difference between PHP GD2 and ImageMagick?

Tags: magento2, speedoptimization

Magento 2 Image Processing Settings: Image Adapter

What is the difference between PHP GD2 and ImageMagick? 
Which one is fast(optimizing website speed) and which one should be recommended?

Answer (score 0):

[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319203/imagemagick-vs-gd-which-is-faster-less-resource-intensive-and-produces-better)

> I would lean towards ImageMagick as far as image quality goes. It seems to produce considerably sharper/higher-quality images than GD2 (at the expense of larger filesize.)
>
> ImageMagick is also not bound by PHP's memory limit.

[You can also read this](https://www.sitepoint.com/imagick-vs-gd/)

Comment: Which one you recommended for speed and quality both (balanced)?